# Flutter Image Cropper unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, cropper

After using the image_cropper plugin for my Flutter app, I get this error:

```
Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.habbyt.version1/cache/image_cropper_1606070878133.jpg
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
<asynchronous suspension>
```

This is my code to crop the image:

```
  _cropImage(filePath) async {
    File croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: filePath,
      aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
      maxWidth: 1080,
      maxHeight: 1080,
    );
    if (croppedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = croppedImage;
        imageExists = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

I visualise the image with AssetImage(_image.path).

This error only occurs after I started the emulator. As soon as I make one hot reload, I can see the image, it displays correctly, and I never get this error again. But as soon as I restart the emulator, the error occurs again.
I also tested it on a real device and the error occurs constantly.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

My fix:

**OLD**

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(filePath);
```

**NEW**

```
final ByteData bytes= file.readAsBytesSync().buffer.asByteData()
```

Comment: where did you make the change ?